# SQL Server returns error with sp_trace_generateevent

Tags: sql-server

I get an error from one of my databases when trying to execute this one

```sql
create or alter procedure [dbo].[test_sp]
with execute as owner
as
SELECT SUSER_SNAME()+ ' '+ USER_NAME();
begin
    exec master..sp_trace_generateevent @eventid = 82   ,
    @userinfo=N'test'
end
GO
exec [dbo].[test_sp]
```

Error:

> Msg 8189, Level 14, State 10, Procedure master..sp_trace_generateevent, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 9]
> You do not have permission to run 'SP_TRACE_GENERATEEVENT'.

Granted `ALTER TRACE` to my user (which returns in `SUSER_SNAME()`), but it wasn't help

The same script on the second database (same server) works without errors.

What else can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run this with EXECUTE AS OWNER, and the owner is a database-level principal and you can't operate outside the current database while impersonating a database-level principal.  Switch to EXECUTE AS CALLER (the default) to have the caller's identity used to run the proc in master.  eg

```
create or alter procedure [dbo].[test_sp]
with execute as caller
as
SELECT SUSER_SNAME()+ ' '+ USER_NAME();
begin
    exec master..sp_trace_generateevent @eventid = 82,  @userinfo  = N'test'
end
GO
exec [dbo].[test_sp]
```

This can be made to work with owner-impersonation by marking the database as TRUSTWORTHY. See: [Extending Database Impersonation by Using EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms188304(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [Guidelines for using the TRUSTWORTHY database setting in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/guidelines-for-using-the-trustworthy-database-setting-in-sql-server-40fd093f-23cb-882d-ea05-7a3b19be7d9b)

Comment: Much appreciated. It was TRUSTWORTHY